# To whom does Mickey think he could ask questions?

Tags: plot-explanation, judy

In the 2019 movie *Judy*, Judy has to do more concert shows to get custody of her children but she didn't like doing any more shows:

> Mickey: I don't think it's anybody's fault. I think maybe I could have asked more questions upfront.

Who does he think he could have asked more questions from?